# Unable to get twitter email via twitter login using omniauth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-4, omniauth

I am using devise gem for authenticating login via omniauth-twitter gem. i am unable to get email from the response params.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: important thing in Twitter authentication is Twitter will not provide you email address for any reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twitter doesn't provide email address via OAuth. [Proof](https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/4019)